# Seeming discrepancy in XSLT 2.0's evaluation of exists()

Tags: xslt, xpath

Input is an XML document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input>
  <Scopes>
    <Scope>Issuance</Scope>
    <Scope>TimeSeries</Scope>
    <Scope>MonthlyDisclosures</Scope>
  </Scopes>
  <AsyncFlag>true</AsyncFlag>
</input>
```

Two different developers wrote XPATHs to evaluate this XML document; the gist of their XPATHs is:

"If either `<Scope>MonthlyCollateral</Scope>` or  `<Scope>MegaUltimateCollateral</Scope>` is in the input document, and `<AsyncFlag>` = true, then execute the following block of XSLT".

Developer one wrote her XPATH in this form:

```
<xsl:if test="(exists(/input/Scopes[Scope='MonthlyCollateral']) or exists(/input/Scopes[Scope='MegaUltimateCollateral' ])) and /input/AsyncFlag='true' ">
```

Developer two wrote his XPATH in this form:

```
<xsl:if test="exists(/input/Scopes[Scope='MonthlyCollateral'] or /input/Scopes[Scope='MegaUltimateCollateral' ]) and /input/AsyncFlag='true' ">
```

Version one uses two separate exists() calls combined with an "or", while version two uses one exists() call that contains to or-ed together XPATHs.

With the XML document shown at the top my posting, both of these tests should evaluate to false; however, only the first one returns the expected result of false.

After reading Michael's response, I decided to distill this down to its essence -- "why does exists(xpath-1 or xpath-2) evaluate to true when neither xpath-1 nor xpath-2 evaluate to true.

The following returns *true* when evaluated against the XML document:

```
exists(/input/Scopes[Scope='Issuance'])
```

The following returns *false* when evaluated against the XML document:

```
exists(/input/Scopes[Scope='MegaUltimateCollateral'])
```

The following returns *true* when evaluated against the XML document:

```
exists(/input/Scopes[Scope='MegaUltimateCollateral'] or /input/Scopes[Scope='Issuance'])
```

The following returns *true* when evaluated against the XML document:

```
exists(/input/Scopes[Scope='MegaUltimateCollateral'] or /input/Scopes[Scope='MonthlyCollateral'])
```

The first three make sense to me -- at least one of the XPATHs does indeed select a , therefore it does "exist".  The last one, however, still does not make sense to me; neither MegaUltimateCollateral nor MonthlyCollateral exists within /input/Scopes, therefore in my (perhaps anachronistic) reading of "or", the exists() should evaluate to false, not true.

Comment: "*After reading Michael's response, I decided to distill this down to its essence..*" The essence is still the same as before: the `exists()` function has only one argument. When that argument is an expression - as it is in your example - then the argument is evaluated first, and then the `exists()` function operates on the result of that evaluation. In this case, the result of the evaluation will be either `true` or `false`. The `exists()` function returns `false` **only** when its argument is an empty sequence. Neither `true` nor `false` are an empty sequence.

Comment: P.S. Perhaps you are confusing `exists(a or b)` with `exists(a | b)`. The former will **always** be `true`, while the latter will return `false` when neither `a` nor `b` exist (i.e. when the union of `a` and `b` is an empty sequence).

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Comment: Yes, Michael.hor257K answered my question for me, and I upvoted it.

Comment: If your question is answered, please close it by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/245750). -- "*I upvoted it.*" No, you haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am struggling to understand why Version two returns true.

Because both:

```
exists(true())
```

and:

```
exists(false())
```

return `true`. You have a Boolean expression inside the `exists()` function, and the result of that Boolean expression will always "exist" one way or another (if that has any meaning).

---

**IMPORTANT:**

Note that the first test too is incorrect (IIUC), because it lacks parentheses around the `or` expression.

And, to go by your description, it should test for `not(exists())` rather than `exists()`.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  The original code actually did have parentheses around the two exists(), but I failed to copy it verbatim from the XSLT.  Also, I incorrectly characterized the desired evaluation as "neither/nor" when I should have said "either/or".